# Unable to create reports using Iframe

Tags: apex, reporting, iframe

When I am including a report in Iframe I am getting this error:

> Refused to display
>   'https://ap1.salesforce.com/00O90000007bVAv?isdtp=mn' in a frame
>   because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'

Can any one pls help me very urgent.

Comment: Is the report you are trying to include in the iFrame in the same org as your VisualForce page? 'X-Frame-Options' being set to 'SAMEORIGIN' is to prevent [ClickJacking](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking). It means that report can only be displayed in a iframe from the same origin.

Comment: You might try using the Analytics API instead.

Comment: Hi, If I use Analytics API How can I integrate standard report with the Visual force filters?